# Magento: How to display how many times a product has been added to wishlist?

Tags: magento

Magento: How to display how many times a product has been added to wishlist? Including all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Below code it is working from my end to get total number of wish list added by all customer for particular prodduct

```
    $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection();
    $wishlist->getSelect()                  
                     ->where('main_table.product_id =  '.$_product->getId());
    echo $count = $wishlist->count();

    exit;
```